# xamarin forms cannot convert TEAL into SYSTEM.DOUBLE

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Created blank project and following a tutorial for a search box (running from the MainPage.xaml) but it won't Deploy.
Crashes with error: `System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot convert TEAL into SYSTEM.DOUBLE`

Build succeeds but when I try to run it, it crashes on the MainPage.xaml.g.cs on the following function

```
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlG", "0.0.0.0")]
    private void InitializeComponent() {
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml(this, typeof(MainPage));
        ColorsSearchBar = global::Xamarin.Forms.NameScopeExtensions.FindByName<global::Xamarin.Forms.SearchBar>(this, "ColorsSearchBar");
        ColorsListView = global::Xamarin.Forms.NameScopeExtensions.FindByName<global::Xamarin.Forms.ListView>(this, "ColorsListView");
        SuggestionsListView = global::Xamarin.Forms.NameScopeExtensions.FindByName<global::Xamarin.Forms.ListView>(this, "SuggestionsListView");
    }
```

please see my code below...does anyone know what I am doing wrong.

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    List<string> colors = new List<string> { "Red", "Blue", "Green", "Yellow" };

    ObservableCollection<string> myColors = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void Handle_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        var color = e.Item as string;

        myColors.Add(color);

        ColorsListView.ItemsSource = myColors;

        SuggestionsListView.IsVisible = false;
    }

    void Handle_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var keyword = ColorsSearchBar.Text;

        if(keyword.Length >= 1)
        {
            var suggestions = colors.Where(c => c.ToLower().Contains(keyword.ToLower()));

            SuggestionsListView.ItemsSource = suggestions;
            SuggestionsListView.IsVisible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            SuggestionsListView.IsVisible = false;
        }
    }
}

  <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10,20,10,0" Spacing="0">
    <Label Text="Xamarin.Forms" FontSize="46" TextColor="Purple" />
    <Label Text="MVVM, Search Page" FontSize="Teal"/>
    <SearchBar x:Name="ColorsSearchBar" TextChanged="Handle_TextChanged"/>
    <Grid>
        <ListView x:Name="ColorsListView" />
        <ListView x:Name="SuggestionsListView" ItemTapped="Handle_ItemTapped" BackgroundColor="Silver"/>
    </Grid>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not valid

```
FontSize="Teal"
```

Comment: Forgive the amateur hour....missed that...should have been FontSize="30" TextColor="Teal" thanks Jason

Comment: @John, it seems that Jason's reply solved your issue, so please remember to mark Jason's reply as answer, thanks.